# Isotope packery layout stacking images

Tags: jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope, packery

I am trying to make a packery layout that uses the the width of an image. Whether it is 400px or the width of the entire container, I would like to fill up the space with my images. I don't want any whitespace either. Can someone tell where I am going wrong. Code and codepen are below.

```
<div class="grid" style="width:1200px; height:100%; background:salmon">
<!--    <div class="grid-sizer"></div> -->
  <div class="grid-item one"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px" /></div>
  <div class="grid-item two"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px"/></div>
  <div class="grid-item three"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" style="width:300px"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item one"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" style="width:600px"/></div>
  <div class="grid-item two"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" style="width:900px"/></div>
  <div class="grid-item three"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" style="width:300px"/></div>
</div>

$('.grid').isotope({
  // options
  layoutMode: 'packery',
  packery: {
    columnWidth: '.grid-item'
  },
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true

});
```

http://codepen.io/Jesders88/pen/GrpqQr

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and switched to a packery package.

Take a look at this link http://packery.metafizzy.co/

When I tried using isotope with a packery layout mode it didn't work: http://demoserver.co.za/test2.html

When I switched to the above it worked great: http://demoserver.co.za/test3.html